# Simple string manipulation with brackets

Tags: javascript, string

Looking for the most efficient way to change this string `000` into `[0][0][0]`.

Comment: just that string or any string?

Comment: Split into array or it is a string?

Comment: What does `[0][0][0]` mean here? Is this just a string?

Comment: Not into an array keep it a string.

Comment: @MinusFour yes just a string, sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One more way would be to use regular expression, such that

```
'000'.replace(/0/g, '[0]')
```

Comment: This is length-proof, too, i.e. you may not know how many zeros there are in the input string, and this solution will still work.

Comment: Niceeeeeeee! perfect, thank you! will mark correct in few minutes when I can.

Answer (score 4):

How about using `split` and `join`:

```
'[' + '000'.split('').join('][') + ']'
```

Or with a regex with `replace`:

```
'000'.replace(/\d/g, function (el) { return '[' + el + ']'; })
```

Comment: I'm doing it dynamically so it's running through a loop... I don't know the length it could be any of these values  0 | 00 | 000 | 0000 | etc...

Comment: And now you don't need the loop anymore, and the length doesn't matter in this answer

Answer (score 1):

```
'000'.split('').map(e => `[${e}]`).join('')
```